# I cannot see my installed programs

Tags: software-installation

I have Kubuntu 14.04. when I install program via the software center or via the terminal somehow it doesn't appear in my launcher. I can do researching it doesn't find it.

I know that there is something to update maybe manually for it to appears but at this stage I don't know what to do.

Comment: Well... Thanks for your prompt answer. However, how do I put them in my launcher once I found where they are?

Comment: It is best to comment on the actual answer, not your question as otherwise the answerer doesn't get a notification that you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, GTK apps (like most Gnome apps) will not show up in the menu or search function for QT based desktops (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntustudio etc.) especially if there is a QT based counterpart for the app.
 You can usually make a custom launcher for those apps.

To search for apps manually, use `dpkg -l | grep` . For example, to search for installed apps that have the word "photo" in the name or description, type the following in an open terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep photo
```

You should see something like this output ("ii" precedes the name of installed packages).

```
ii  darktable                              0.9.3-2ubuntu1                                      virtual lighttable and darkroom for photographers
ii  libgphoto2-2                           2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2                                   gphoto2 digital camera library
ii  libgphoto2-l10n                        2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2                                   gphoto2 digital camera library - localized messages
ii  libgphoto2-port0                       2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2                                   gphoto2 digital camera port library
ii  rawtherapee                            3.0.0~dfsg1-1build1                                 Free RAW converter and digital photo processing software
ii  shotwell                               0.12.3-0ubuntu0.1                                   digital photo organizer
```

Comment: user296539 wrote "Well... Thanks for your prompt answer. However, how do I put them in my launcher once I found where they are?" On his answer so you won't have been notified. I have copied it to here.